# Using the mapping plugin of Knockout in an Asp.Net MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have this code and it work perfectly:

```
<script>
   $(function() {
      var modelAsString = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));

      myProject.initialize(ko.mapping.fromJS(modelAsString));
   });
</script>
```

Note that this script is directly in my view (e.g. MyPage.cshtml)

I'm just wondering why I must use the function **fromJS** instead of **fromJSON**.

If I use **fromJSON**, there is no error but it seems like my viewmodel is not created correctly.

And if possible, it would be greatly appreciated to have an example where I can use fromJSON with the same context; a case where I directly get the Model from the view instead of getting it from an ajax query.

Comment: Why is it a problem that you need to use fromJS?

Comment: It's not a problem. I just want to understand why fromJSON don't work in this case and what I must provide if I want to use fromJSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ko.mapping.fromJSON` takes a JSON **string** then parses it and calls `ko.mapping.fromJS` internally with the parsed JavaScript object. However if you call `ko.mapping.fromJSON` with something which is not a string it returns `null` so no mapping will happen.

So in your case you need to change your `modelAsString` to hold JavaScript string with wrapping the result of the `Html.Raw` call with apostrophes then you can use `ko.mapping.fromJSON` on it:

```
var modelAsString = '@(Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)))';

myProject.initialize(ko.mapping.fromJSON(modelAsString));
```

Also form the mapping plugin [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) (emphasis added by me):

> Working with JSON strings
>
> If your Ajax call returns a **JSON string** (and does not deserialize it
>   into a JavaScript object), then you can use the function
>   `ko.mapping.fromJSON` to create and update your view model instead. To
>   unmap, you can use `ko.mapping.toJSON`.
>
> Apart from the fact that they work with JSON strings instead of JS
>   objects **these functions are completely identical to their *JS
>   counterparts.**

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I want to know.